# Organic material creation in UDK

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I'm trying to generate my own procedural map in UDK to create an organic ooze material.

I have searched the docs at epic and I couldn't find a location to cover the topic of creating movement/transitions within the map. Is there a way with unreal script to code the variances in the surface over time?

I was assuming I could transition between 3-4 images but I can't find the solution.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve? What do you mean with "movement/transitions within the map"? Movement of objects in the level during gameplay or when editing the level? "Variance in the surface over time" could be implemented in different ways depending on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: by map I do not mean the UDK environment.. I mean the material / texture on the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by procedural. Procedural in games means to generate a level or the world from a (randomly generated) number.

For your question, it is possible to fade/blend from one texture to another in a material in UDK. But UnrealScript is not the best point to start.
Use the [lerp node](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/MaterialsCompendium.html#LinearInterpolate) in the material editor for that. Plug texture 1 in A and textures 2 in B. Calculate a value between 0 and 1 to blend between the two and plug that in Alpha of the lerp node.

You can chain multiple lerp node together by plugging a lerp node in the B of another lerp node, but I suggest that to get it working for just 2 textures to understand how it works first.

You can calculate the blending value/Alpha dependent on time by using the time node.

As you are properly not familiar with materials in UDK, I suggest that you watch this excellent [tutorial video about materials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9kIV8D83QU) from 3DBuzz. This will give you the basic understanding how materials in UDK work. After that you will know what exactly I was trying to explain in this post. 1 hour may seem a bit long, but it is easy to understand and follow and I watched the whole thing, too, when I started with UDK.